# Rails で ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeErrorが解消されないです．

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

#### 前提・実現したいこと

アプリを開発しております．その中で，通知機能を実装し調節している中で上記の**ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError**が出てしまいました．　解消したいです．

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError in PostsController#create
unknown attribute 'visiter_id' for Notification.
```

#### 該当のソースコード

```
rails c にてモデルNotification の確認結果

irb(main):001:0> Notification.new
(0.2ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
TRANSACTION (0.0ms)  begin transaction　=> #<Notification:0x0000562096ee9d98
id: nil,
visitor_id: nil, 
visited_id: nil,
post_id: nil,
reply_id: nil,
action: "",
checked: false,
created_at: nil,
updated_at: nil>
```

```
migrate/create_notifications.rb

class CreateNotifications < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :notifications do |t|
      t.integer :visitor_id, null: false
      t.integer :visited_id, null: false
      t.integer :post_id
      t.integer :reply_id
      t.string :action, default: '', null: false
      t.boolean :checked, default: false, null: false

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :notifications, :visitor_id
    add_index :notifications, :visited_id
    add_index :notifications, :post_id
    add_index :notifications, :reply_id

  end
end
```

#### 追加情報

```
post_create.rb

class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!


  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.user_id = current_user.id
    @post.sender_id = current_user.id
    @receiver = User.where.not(id:current_user.id).order(:received_at).first
    @post.receiver_id = @receiver.id
    @post.save!

    @post.create_notification_by(current_user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to request.referrer}
      format.js
    end


    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
      pp e.record.errors

    @receiver.update!(received_at: :Time.now)

    redirect_to posts_path
  end


    private
        def post_params
          params.require(:post).permit(:dear, :content, :from, :sender_id, :receiver_id, :user_id)
        end
end
```

```
model/post.rb

def create_notification_by(current_user)
    notification=current_user.active_notifications.new(
      post_id:self.id,
      visited_id: self.receiver_id,
      action:"post"
    )
    notification.save if notification.valid?
  end
```

#### 試したこと

以下の記事にあるようなことをとりあえずやってみましたがなんともうまくいきません．
確かですが，visiter_idというエラーにある書き方は最初にやってました．なので，直さなきゃ！と思って直したつもりで，実際コンソールで確認しても直せたつもりだったんですが．．．

[unknown attribute '○○○○' for ○○○. →カラムのリネーム](https://qiita.com/Ayaka_ramens/items/f0c68b08fcf6145c2b17)
[bin/rails db:reset が効かない](https://hiyoko-programing.hatenablog.com/entry/2020/09/08/141001)

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

ruby 3.0.2
rails 7.0.1

Answer (score 1):

メッセージの中に `visitor_id` と `visiter_id` が混在しています（o と e）。打ち間違いしていないでしょうか。

また、エラーが出ているのは `PostsController#create` なので、まず見るべきは `PostsController` での実装です。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます，ポストコントローラとモデルも追加しました．

Comment: おそらく `@post.create_notification_by(current_user)` の先で発生しています。エラーメッセージに表示されているであろうコールスタックを読んでください。